# Pandas throwing "Error tokenizing data. C error" while loading data sets from URL

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, csv, kaggle

I am trying to work on the Titanic competition to get hands on experience with data science & machine learning.  I tried to load up the datasets from GitHub but pandas threw the following error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 32, saw 2
```

I tried to follow the advice of other SO users so I added `skiprows=1` parameter in my `pd.csv()` call to skip the first row but it didn't work.

```
import pandas as pd

train_dataset = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/oo92/titanic-files/blob/master/train.csv", skiprows=1)
test_dataset = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/oo92/titanic-files/blob/master/test.csv", skiprows=1)
ground_truths = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/oo92/titanic-files/blob/master/gender_submission.csv", skiprows=1)

train_dataset.head()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path that you are accessing from is a Github repository page which is a webpage, it does not return CSV. You have to click on 'raw' option in Github and then pass the URL which in your case is:

```
test = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Titanic-Kaggle/master/test.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you.  But Spyder doesn't let me print the head with `train_dataset.head()`.  I have to explicitly place it inside a `print()` cal.